# How to display Laplace operator as self-adjoint?

Tags: functional-analysis, harmonic-functions

How to display Laplace operator as self-adjoint?

I've read some hints about using Green's second identity and had some other ideas regarding constructing a matrix with the Laplace operator terms in the diagonal that's positive definite.

Answer (score 4):

I'll just highlight the key points, there's a fair amount of details to fill in regarding function spaces.  But at least formally, one can show

$$(-\Delta u, v)_{\Omega} = (\nabla u, \nabla v)_{\Omega} + \langle \nabla u \cdot \mathbf{n}, \gamma v \rangle = (u, -\Delta v)_{\Omega},$$

where $\mathbf{n}$ would be the normal vector to the domain $\Omega$, $\gamma$ is the trace, $\langle \cdot, \cdot \rangle$ is the duality/inner product on the boundary of $\Omega$ and $(\cdot, \cdot)_{\Omega}$ is the $L^2$ inner product.

The adjoint of an operator is basically the thing when you move it to the other side of the inner product.  By using Green's theorem to move $-\Delta$ to the other side of the inner product, we see we get $-\Delta$ back.  This means that the operator is self-adjoint.

Comment: Matt, if u,v are 1-forms will your first term on the RHS be using exterior derivatives?

Comment: @R.Rankin I'm sorry but I am not familiar with exterior calculus.